# Fire JQuery code on appearance of background image?

Tags: jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery(function ($) {

                $.supersized({

                    // Functionality
                    slide_interval: 5000,       // Length between transitions
                    transition: 1,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                    transition_speed: 700,      // Speed of transition

                    // Components                           
                    slide_links: 'blank',   // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
                    slides: [           // Slideshow Images
                                                        { image: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8080/8339311971_cb6706842b_h.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8080/8339311971_cb6706842b_h.jpg', url: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8080/8339311971_cb6706842b_h.jpg' },
                                                        { image: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8345/8208481483_fc6b1bdf7d_h.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8345/8208481483_fc6b1bdf7d_h.jpg', url: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8345/8208481483_fc6b1bdf7d_h.jpg' },
                                                        { image: 'http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7055/6866255833_cf22b71843_b.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb: 'http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7055/6866255833_cf22b71843_b.jpg', url: 'http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7055/6866255833_cf22b71843_b.jpg' },
                                                        { image: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8487/8185988415_62ca8175e9_h.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Colin Wojno', thumb: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8487/8185988415_62ca8175e9_h.jpg', url: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8487/8185988415_62ca8175e9_h.jpg' },
                                                        { image: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8079/8340357550_397f7e09e3_h.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Colin Wojno', thumb: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8079/8340357550_397f7e09e3_h.jpg', url: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8079/8340357550_397f7e09e3_h.jpg' },
                                                        { image: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8490/8187033496_cf9587943c_h.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Colin Wojno', thumb: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8490/8187033496_cf9587943c_h.jpg', url: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8490/8187033496_cf9587943c_h.jpg' },
                                                        { image: 'http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6002/5923622568_46d8e065cc_b.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Brooke Shaden', thumb: 'http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6002/5923622568_46d8e065cc_b.jpg', url: 'http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6002/5923622568_46d8e065cc_b.jpg' },
                                                        { image: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8502/8339293377_a1574a28be_h.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Brooke Shaden', thumb: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8502/8339293377_a1574a28be_h.jpg', url: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8502/8339293377_a1574a28be_h.jpg' },
                                                        { image: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8497/8339319687_629c824dc1_h.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Brooke Shaden', thumb: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8497/8339319687_629c824dc1_h.jpg', url: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8497/8339319687_629c824dc1_h.jpg' }
                    ]

                });
            });

        </script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        function loop(){
      $("#p1").delay("1000").fadeIn("slow");
      $("#p2").delay("1000").fadeIn("slow");
      $("#p1").delay("3000").fadeOut("slow");
      $("#p2").delay("3000").fadeOut("slow");
      $("#p3").delay("6000").fadeIn("slow");
      $("#p3").delay("3000").fadeOut("slow");
      $("#p4").delay("12000").fadeIn("slow");
      $("#p4").delay("3000").fadeOut("slow");
      $("#p5").delay("18000").fadeIn("slow");
      $("#p5").delay("3000").fadeOut("slow");
      $("#p6").delay("24000").fadeIn("slow");
      $("#p6").delay("3000").fadeOut("slow");
      $("#p7").delay("30000").fadeIn("slow");
      $("#p7").delay("3000").fadeOut("slow");
      $("#p8").delay("35000").fadeIn("slow");
      $("#p8").delay("3000").fadeOut("slow");
      $("#p9").delay("41000").fadeIn("slow");
      $("#p9").delay("3000").fadeOut("slow");
      $("#p10").delay("46000").fadeIn("slow");
      $("#p10").delay("4084").fadeOut("slow",loop);
        }
        loop();
    });


</script>
```

Ok dudes, here's the problem. I've got a full background slideshow which I would like to sync up with some text that will appear on screen. As you can see, this text is represented by the 'p' fadeIns. My problem is that my current method for ensuring that the text always appears on the correct background slide is just to delay the last image, which is less than ideal as it goes out of sync. I'd appreciate someone telling me a better way this can be done :D I was thinking we could tell the fadeIn function to activate as soon as the first background image appears on screen, but an unsure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should put the code to fade the text inside the theme's function [theme.beforeAnimation()](http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html#theme-before), if you are using the default theme (shutter) check the file supersized.shutter.js and search for 'beforeAnimation : function(direction){'.

Another (ugly) way could be:

- Setup the slide show to off
- Use the API to transition the slides 'manually' with the text you want using [api.nextslide()](http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html#api-nextslide)

**EDIT:**
First make sure you are using the template version that is not minified: In the head of your html you will find this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="theme/supersized.shutter.min.js"></script>
```

replace with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="theme/supersized.shutter.js"></script>
```

then edit the supersized.shutter.js file and add the follow lines inside the beforeAnimation() function (line 239)

```
$('[id^="p"]').fadeOut(); 
$('#p' + (vars.current_slide + 1)).delay(500).fadeIn("slow");
```

Because I don't know how is your html I am hiding all elements with id that starts with 'p', it is better if you improve this selector $('[id^="p"]').fadeOut();. 
That is it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, that's a really good idea! I'll definitely try it!! I'm going to mark you correct for having a good idea :D

Comment: Although I'm not sure how it would affect the slideshow with all the delays, maybe I could just call the Fading function but still keep the code blocks separate?

Comment: I think it wouldn't affect the slideshow because the transitions are being controlled by the setInterval, that is why you have to set the slideshow to off.

Comment: I was talking about the first method, where you paste the code inside the function. Seems like it would slow the slideshow down.

Comment: Don't worry it won't. just remove the delay because it is not necessary, keep track of the text number to hide the previous and show the next text correctly. That is it.

Comment: Hi bertrand, I'm having trouble with this, I'm new to coding and I don't really know how to proceed.

Comment: Don't worry you will get it. Let me edit my answer to put the solution I would use. Just to confirm, you are using the default (shutter) theme right?

Comment: Yes that's right I'm using the default, thanks for taking the time to help